# Adding additional language on Alexa skill after certification

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

My skill is live, but I'm keen to add additional language capability to the skill. However, my question is whether I can do this without having to re-submit the skill? I've added the tabs, for say English (India).

Answer (score 1):

You should submit it back for certification for any change you made with the existing certified version, which includes adding additional languages as well. Your changes will not reflect in production until you get certified.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to update the AWS Lambda function no problem. But if you wish to edit intents and slots you have to edit the development version and have it certified again. This is the case as of 10/2017